# Node npm error on windows looking for tools version

Tags: javascript, node.js, msbuild, npm, windows-8.1

Im trying to use node and when i go to install the npm packages via 'npm install package.json'
I am currently using windows 8.1 as my os. It began when I started using redis but im not sure if it is because of redis.  The error I get is

> MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized.
>   Available tools versions are "4.0".

The full console print out is [here](http://pastebin.com/CR42N8YW)

If anyone has come across this error and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Look below for @Abdel-Rahman Shoman it is the most recent way of doing it.
Thanks for the update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install Visual Studio or Visual Studio Express 2013. You can download them here:
http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

Comment: Any way to get msbuild without the +6GB IDE?

Comment: Instead of full VS 2013, you can install just MS Build Tools, but you need to find the right version. Another solution is to tell `npm` to use another version of the compiler that you already have installed:
`npm install package.json --msvs_version=2013`

Comment: hero of the month: @quasoft `msvs_version` is really undocumented, but at the same time is a solution for a so vast number of compile problems

It's also permanent using `npm config set msvs_version 2013` (or 2015)

Comment: @GergoErdosi I have installed MS BuilD Tool 2013, but it has MSBUILD of version "12.0". Where I can download MSBUILD v "2.0"?

Comment: Why do you suggest installing full huge VS? MS offers all build tools as standalone downloads. What's the point to install VS then? Can't we use just those MSBuild tools alone?

Comment: This worked for me `choco install microsoft-build-tools --version 14.0.25420.1`  However, you will need chocolatey installed.

Answer (score 76):

Provided that you have Nodejs installed, start Windows CMD in admin mode and run the following:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

and restart your PC afterwards.

Comment: Helped! Tried on Windows 10 without Visual Studio installed.

Comment: This solved it for me without having to install VS 2013 (or any other version)

Comment: Works, but ATTENTION: After installation, the system reboots **immediately without any confirmation!** That's not acceptable and can be very dangerous, depending what you're doing/what's running on the machine...

Comment: This worked, without doing anything related to Visual Studio :)

Comment: January'19: This worked but then I kept having the error "MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0".

Installing version 4 of the window-build-tools solved my problem. More details here: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/152

This should be solved eventually, though.

Comment: Worked but needed restart.

Comment: This did not work for me. Installer just freezes. Also tried getting it @ version 4, in this case a bunch of URLs could not be resolved and it crashed. I ended up installing Windows 10 SDK instead.

Comment: you can download MS build tools separately too. here is the link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40760
Reference: https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/issues/60

Answer (score 9):

Since most of the answers here are from 2015, thought I provide a fresh guide.

MS build tools can be installed without installing Visual studio. The link below [Check step 3] shows how to install "Visual Studio Installer". You can use it to install the required MS build tools.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-3---

Following is a screenshot of the workloads I installed

[image]

**P.S:** You might need to restart your machine

Comment: Are all these "workloads" necessary? UWF adds a lot of gigabytes

Comment: Just installing Node.js build tools work for me!

Answer (score 4):

Finally Microsoft is providing [much better solution](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245) to build native Node.js packages.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Answer (score 2):

As of current you can grab Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Comment: ya I got it fixed around the time I was doing it. There was a file needed from the visual studio setup that corrected itself when i installed it

Answer (score 2):

Open up a new cmd as administrator and run this command:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

then

```
npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
```

close all instances of shell/cmd, reopen a cmd (regular this time, non-administrator) return to your directory where you are trying to run npm install and run it again

**NOTE:**

If you're seeing this in 2019, you may need

```
npm config set msvs_version 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

These  commands worked for me.

```
 & npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools
 & npm config set python "%USERPROFILE%\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
 & npm install -g windows-build-tools
 & npm install.
 & npm start.
```

Solution found [here](https://easytechnolearn.blogspot.com/2019/05/msbuild-error-msb4132-tools-version-20.html)

Answer (score 0):

Installing MS Build Tool 2013 Solved my problem.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

Answer (score 0):

**Please run the below command to fix this issue MSBUILD: error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0".**

```
=> open git bash or CMD after go to project path 
=> npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools
=> npm config set python "%USERPROFILE%\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
=> npm install -g windows-build-tools
=> npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install all you need Node.js, VSCode, Python 2.7, etc.
2. Run as admin VSCode.
3. In VSCode bash write `npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015`
4. `npm install`

Works on Windows 11.